# Replace NULL or NA in a column wrt to other column in pandas data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a table:

```
        df = pd.DataFrame([[0.1, 2, 55, 0,np.nan],
               [0.2, 4, np.nan, 1,99],
               [0.6, np.nan, 22, 5,88],
               [1.4, np.nan, np.nan, 4,77]],
               columns=list('ABCDE'))

    A    B     C  D     E
0  0.1  2.0  55.0  0   NaN
1  0.2  NaN   NaN  1  99.0
2  0.6  NaN  22.0  5  88.0
3  1.4  NaN   NaN  4  77.0
```

I want to replace NaN values in Column B based on condition on Column A. 
Example:

```
When  B is NULL and value in `column A > 0.2 and < 0.6` replace "NaN" in column B as 5
When B is NULL value in `column A > 0.6 and < 2` replace "NaN" in column B as 10
```

I tried something like this:

```
   if df["A"]>=val1 and pd.isnull(df['B']):
       df["B"]=5
  elif df["A"]>=val2 and df["A"]<val3 and pd.isnull(df['B']):
       df["B"]=10
  elif df["A"]<val4 and pd.isnull(df['B']):
       df["B"]=15
```

The above code is not working.

Please let me know is there any other alternative approach using for loop or apply functions to iterate over pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mask:

```
df['B'] = df['B'].mask((df['A']>0.2) & (df['A']<0.6), df['B'].fillna(5))
df['B'] = df['B'].mask((df['A']>0.6) & (df['A']<2), df['B'].fillna(10))
```

or you can try np.where but it will involve a long condition I guess.